# Running .bat file from Powershell script with parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, parameters

The 'Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment' is a shortcut I use that specifically runs this- 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat" '.

What I'm trying to do is run this command in a Powershell script, and then run *another* command within that new window. The command I need to run is oscdimg, which can't run straight in powershell, this .bat file needs to run first, and then the long oscdimg inside that. Here's my current script. All the comments at the end are different approaches I've already taken with no success. The furthest I've gotten is starting the .bat file fine, but with the incorrect parameter passed through I think. Thanks for any help

Per request,  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcsJv.jpg) is a much simpler example of what I'm trying to do. This small script runs cmd, and attempts to add arguments to change directories, but the resulting cmd window doesn't do that.

```
$srcDIR = Read-Host -Prompt 'Paste the Source Files Directory '
$destDIR = Read-Host -Prompt 'Paste the output destination, with .iso extension '

$etfsbootDIR = "$srcDIR\boot\etfsboot.com"
$efisysDIR = "$srcDIR\efi\microsoft\boot\efisys.bin"

$etfsboot = "`"" + $etfsbootDIR + "`""
$efisys = "`"" + $efisysDIR + "`""
$src = "`"" + $srcDIR + "`""
$dest = "`"" + $destDIR + "`""

$dir8 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg"
$dir10 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg"

if(Test-Path $dir8) { 
    # cd $dir8 
    $etftest = $dir8 + "\etfsboot.com"
}
elseif(Test-Path $dir10){ 
    # cd $dir10 
    $etftest = $dir10 + "\etfsboot.com"
}
else{
    "No Assessment and Deployment Kit detected."
    return
}

$etft = "`"" + $etftest + "`""

if(Test-Path $etfsbootDIR) { "etfsboot.com found at $etfsboot" }
if(Test-Path $efisysDIR)   { "efisys.bin found at $efisys"     }

$beginning = "./oscdimg.exe -m -o -u2 -udfver102 -bootdata:2#p0,e,b"
$middle = "#pEF,e,b"
$command = $beginning + $etfsboot + $middle + $efisys + " " + $src + " " + $dest

$rest = "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat'"
$shortcut = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Kits\Windows ADK\Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment.lnk"

# Start-Process -FilePath $shortcut -ArgumentList $command
# cmd.exe /c $rest $command
# cmd %1 $rest
# & $rest $command
```

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example of what you're trying to do?
It is possible to pass a variable in either direction, from PowerShell to Batch or from Bach to PowerShell. My assessment is you have too many variables and you're running into escaping issues.
Also, you could put everything into a powershell script, and then have the script write out the .bat file and execute it.

Comment: See the changed post. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a /c or /k in the beginning of the argument so cmd knows to run it apparently. ( /c runs the argument and closes the window, /k runs it and keeps the window open)

Working Example-

`$command = "/k cd .."`

`Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList $command`